Bounding $\psi(x)-x$ outside a set of finite logarithmic measure
By a 1980 result of Gallagher, assuming the Riemann hypothesis, one has $\psi(x)-x = O(x^{1/2} (\log \log x)^2)$ outside a set of finite logarithmic measure.  I'm wondering what the state-of-the-art bounds on $\psi(x)-x$ outside a set of finite logarithmic measure are, (1) assuming the Riemann hypothesis, and (2) unconditionally.
Here, $\psi(x) = \sum_{p^k \leq x} \log p$ is the second Chebyshev function.
Gallagher reference: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa37/aa37130.pdf

It might also be interesting to ask about bounds assuming both RH and the linear independence of the imaginary parts of the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ (“LI”). This certainly implies $O(x^{1/2}f(x))$ for any function $f(x)$ tending to infinity—but only outside a set of logarithmic density $0$, not a set of finite logarithmic measure (perhaps LI isn't even needed for that).

@GregMartin I wasn't aware of that result!  Can you share the reference?

Rubinstein and Sarnak, "Chebyshev's bias", Experimental Mathematics, 1994. Assuming RH and LI they proved that $(\psi(x)-x)/\sqrt x$ has a limiting logarithmic distribution function; it's inconsistent with the definition of limiting logarithmic distribution function for $|(\psi(x)-x)/\sqrt x| > f(x)$ to occur with positive logarithmic density when $f(x)\to\infty$.
